# Web scraping: How to get specific element from some page?

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I'm developing some scraping software to check if products price are changed or not. To do this I'm sending Web http request to get product page, it returns me whole html page. There are a lot of items to check so I'm doing it in parallel so my internet bandwidth runs out quickly

The main questions:

**Is it possible to send Web  http request with select query to get only specific element from html page**?

Comment: Specific element? No. You should check for an API since that would be far favorable to scraping.

Comment: There is no API for this supplier

Comment: Nice dream, but I don't know of any protocol to request only part of a page from a server. You might be able to work something with a client stream that closes the stream once the element you care about is received, but that's going to happen pretty close to the wire (i.e. direct socket control, maybe?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best (free / cheap) bet is the Html Agility Pack. There are automated solutions out there that have a UI where you stick in the URL and then just point and click to the elements that you want to extract and they generate the info for you. Big $$$ for that stuff though :(. With the Html Agility Pack, you have to create the "xpath" by hand.

Comment: I'm using Html Agility Pack, but I have to download whole html to make it possible to select

Comment: @IvanSukhetskyi, Correct. You cannot download just random portions of HTML. HTML is nothing. Most of the size is from scripts, images, animations, styles, etc. which you don't need to pull.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless the target server supports Range Request. You can send a request to test if the target server accents range request.